# How does a token crowdsale or ICO work for a permissioned Blockchain project?

Tags: private-blockchain, tokens, ico, crowdsale

Filecoin, for example, ran their highly successful ICO on the Ethereum blockchain, though they are gonna operate on a different chain.

AFAIK, main-net tokens can't be used on a private chain. Makes me wonder how token sales work for a private blockchain project. I understand that a crowdsale is just another fund raising mechanism, and [doesn't even need to be related to a 'blockchain project'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28004/can-i-use-ico-initial-coin-offering-to-fund-for-a-non-blockchain-project). However, if a private chain  does use tokens, how would one issue those to crowdsale participants?